# 415 Unsupported Media Type; Angular to ASP.Net Core API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-services, angular8, media-type

I have `ASP.Net Core 2.1 API`. It looks as below.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]string email) {

}
```

When calling from the postman, I had to call the above API as below with the header set as `Content-Type = application/json`

[image]

While calling the same API from  `Angular 8` app.

```
public send(email: string) {
   //other tried option #1 let obj = JSON.stringify(email);
   //other tried option #2 let obj = this.http.post(API.Url, {email});
   /other tried option #3 let obj = 

   return this.http.post(API.Url, email).pipe(
      retry(2)
   );
}
```

This is throwing the below error:-

> 415 Unsupported Media Type;

If the call is updated with headers:-

```
/* httpOptions = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}*/
public send(email: string) {
 return this.http.post(API.User, email , httpOptions).pipe(
  retry(2)
);}
```

It throws the error as

> {"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 1, position 1."]}

How do I call the above API which is accepting a single parameter named email from angular?

Thanks!

Comment: Did any answer work for you? If yes do consider accepting/upvoting them. Thanks!

Comment: @NicholasK, No still the same issue.

Comment: @NicholasK if I tried to pass `{"email": email } ` then 404

Comment: Try that out through the API first. Will it even accept that json?

Comment: @NicholasK, it accepts only when email is passing as just value. Please refer the attachment (Postman) in the post

Answer (score 5):

You need to serialize a string to make it a valid `json` like this:

```
// some example method.
public send(email: string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }); 
    
    const json = JSON.stringify(email); 
    return this.http.post(API.User, json, {headers: headers}).pipe(
      retry(2)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set content type you will need to change your code to

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
return this.http.post(API.Url, email,{headers:headers}).....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send a `valid JSON` because just sending your email id in the message body will not be a valid JSON. You can send as,

```
const details = {
 mailId: "your respective mail Id"
}
```

And try to send these details in the post-call such as,

```
/* httpOptions = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}*/
public send(email: string) {
 return this.http.post(API.User, details, httpOptions).pipe(
  retry(2)
);}
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!